# Remove underscore from select

Tags: oracle, select

In my select statement, a column contains the underscore character `_`.  I want to replace the underscore with a space.  For example, if the result set column contains `CLOSING_COMPANY`, the result should be `CLOSING COMPANY`

Comment: Are you talking about the column name? Or the data in the column?

Comment: u want to change column name or data?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the name of the column in your result set

```
SELECT closing_company AS "CLOSING COMPANY"
  FROM your_table_name
```

If you want to change the data in the column

```
SELECT REPLACE( column_name, '_', ' ' ) 
  FROM your_table_name
```